# F# using HttpPostedFileBase (abstract class as member type)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, f#

I've been converting my MVC Models/Forms from C# into an F# library, but can't seem to figure this one out.  I use [HttpPostedFileBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the original C# model, but I'm confused how to write an F# type that would work in a similar fashion.

```cs
// C#
public class UploadForm()
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadFile { get; set; }
    // UploadFile is the name of the HTML file input on the Razor view
}
```

```ml
// F#
type UploadForm() = 
    member val ItemID = 0 with get, set
    member val Email = "" with get, set
    member val UploadFile = ???
```

I read the F# documentation on abstract [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx), but I'm not overriding any properties here... just trying to say that a given member (UploadFile) should be of a certain type (HttpPostedFileBase).  Is this possible or do I need to write backing code?

Comment: you can add a type with `member val UploadFile : HttpPostedFileBase = null with get, set`

Comment: Thanks for your help!  If you post as reply I will mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give a type in the usual way like this:

```
type UploadForm() = 
    // ... other members
    member val UploadFile : HttpPostedFileBase = null with get, set
```